# How to flag a question for migration to another SE site?

Tags: support, migration

I just wanted to flag [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19149/how-do-i-delete-several-directories-from-temp-directory-using-rmdir-command) for migration to another SE site (if anywhere I think it belongs on SuperUser) but the flagging wizard won't let me do it.

- Why can't I select my own SE site to migrate to?
- How should I deal with the situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only vote to migrate along predefined migration paths, and migration paths are only created between graduate sites for pairs that see a sufficient amount of migrations without too many bad migrations. Since CS.SE is in beta, there are no migration paths from or to it (except for main site to meta which is always there).

Moderators can migrate any question to any site, with two exceptions:

- Questions that have been migrated already cannot be re-migrated.
- Questions that are more than 60 days old cannot be migrated any longer.

If you think a question should be migrated, then:

- Flag or vote to close the question as off-topic.
- Flag the question for a moderator's attention and explain why you think it should be migrated.

Remember that migrations are only for good questions. If a question is off-topic and bad for some other reason (e.g. it's unclear, too opinion-based, etc.), let it be closed in place. If a question has no answers, migration doesn't have a major advantage; you can tell the asker to delete his question here and repost on the right site.